# On proving $\omega^{\epsilon} = \epsilon$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

How can I prove that 
$$\omega^{\epsilon} = \epsilon$$
where $\omega =\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ...\}$ and $\epsilon = \{\omega, \omega^{\omega}, \omega^{\omega^{\omega}}, \omega^{\omega^{\omega^\omega}}, ...\}$

Comment: $\epsilon_0$ is actually defined to be the supremum of $\{ \omega, \omega^{\omega}, \dots \}$. I think this will clarify your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As $\varepsilon_0 = \sup \{\omega, \omega^\omega, \omega^{(\omega^\omega)}, \dots \}$ we know (by the recursive definition of ordinal exponentiation) that $\omega^{\varepsilon_0} = \sup \{\omega^\omega, \omega^{(\omega^\omega)}, \dots,\}$, which is just the supremum of the tail of the same set, so that it also equals $\varepsilon_0$.